# Search string condition overlooking the present instances

Tags: python, string, list, numpy, join

```
print(crop_dataset.shape)
searchfor = ['she', 'he','his','her','him','boys','woman','Woman','girl','men','man','female','girls','person','horse']
indices_list = []
for i in range(5):
    print(crop_dataset['hypothesis'][i])
    if ('|'.join(searchfor)) in crop_dataset['hypothesis'][i]:
        indices_list.append(i)
print(indices_list)    
rows_where_found = crop_dataset.select(indices_list)
print(rows_where_found.shape)
```

This tends to print:

```
(10122, 3)
A person is training his horse for a competition.
A person is at a diner, ordering an omelette.
A person is outdoors, on a horse.
They are smiling at their parents
There are children present
[]
```

What could be the reason that the list is empty?

example printed with 3 elements

```
print(crop_dataset['hypothesis'][0:3])

['A person is training his horse for a competition.', 'A person is at a diner, ordering an omelette.', 'A person is outdoors, on a horse.']
```

I tried via dataframes as well:

```
df_temp = datasets.Dataset.to_pandas(crop_dataset)

rows_where_found = df_temp.filter(lambda example: searchfor in example['hypothesis'])

returns empty
```

Comment: "in" checks for strings as they are. If you need regular expressions there is the "re" module.

Comment: So with searchfor = [r'\bshe\b', r'\bhe\b',r'\bhis\b',r'\bher\b',r'\bhim\b',r'\bboys\b',r'\bwoman\b',r'\bWoman\b',r'\bgirl\b',r'\bmen\b',r'\bman\b',r'\bfemale\b',r'\bgirls\b'] I can pick words with spacers but what is wrong with the if condition?

Comment: To be clear: you are *confused* as to why, to give a more straightforward example, `'x|y' in 'foo bar x baz quux'` would be False? Why, in your own words, should it be true?

Comment: You construct a regular expression like `his|her` but "in" processes it just as string, not as regular expression, and can"t find a `his|her` in the sentences.

Comment: If `\b` is processed outside of the regular expression functions it is just the backspace character. Only when used properly with a regex function it marks a word boundary.

Comment: @manalai added an example

Comment: SO how do we use OR logical operator if not by join method?

Comment: Using "join" is the right way but the resulting string must be processed as regular expression.